# Intercept intent android

Tags: android, flutter

Is there any way to intercept or run a callback before user open any app on their device?

For instance, I need a feature when user opens an app, my app will wake up first, intercept the `intent` (Android) in broadcast recevier, then do something inside our application. At the end, I will call `startActivity(intent)` to open the app that user supposes to open at first.

Comment: As Gabe Sechan said: `That would be a security nightmare...a malware maker's dream API.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  That would be a security nightmare, you're basically asking for a malware maker's dream API.  If its your own personal device you could build a custom version of AOSP which does that, but that would be the only way.